# Bayesian network probability problem. Rainy on 3rd day given it rains on 1st day

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayesian, bayes-theorem, bayesian-network

[image: Bayesian network]

[image]

Given the above bayesian network constructed in order to predict rain during successive days and the conditional probability tables. What would be the probability of P( Rain3∣ Rain1 )?

**My approach:**

There are two possible ways for P( Rain3∣ Rain1 )

1. Either it rains on day 1, not day 2 and day 3 (in the table 0.350)
2. Or rains on day 1, day 2 and day 3 (in the table 0.612)

Let's denote these as random variables A and B respectively.

Therefore shouldn't P( Rain3∣ Rain1 ) = P(A∪B)

And since A and B are given in the table as A=0.350, B=0.612
then P(A∪B) = 0.350 + 0.612 = 0.962

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost had it...

Rains on day 1, not day 2 and day 3 ...

- Given that it rains on day 1, the prob of not raining on day 2 is $1-0.586 = 0.414$
  $$P(R_3 = T \cap R_2 = F | R_1 = T) = (0.414)(0.350) = 0.145 $$
  Rains on day 1, day 2 and day 3 ...
- Given that it rains on day 1, the prob of raining on day 2 is $0.586$
  $$P(R_3 = T \cap R_2 = T | R_1 = T) =0.586(0.612) =  0.359$$

Finally...
$$P(R_3 = T  | R_1 = T) =0.359+0.145 = 0.504 $$

Comment: Agree with your solution, but minor issue: the given probability is 0.586, not 0.568.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I have edited and corrected my answer.